# Association between two tables where keys are different data types

Tags: entity-framework

**Tables**

- Departments
- Employees

I'm trying to associate:

- Departments - dept_code : char(4)
- Employees - dept : varchar(4)

But I receive the following error,

> Error 2039: The conceptual side
>   property 'DEPT_CODE' has already been
>   mapped to a storage property with type
>   'char'. If the conceptual side
>   property is mapped to multiple
>   properties in the storage model, make
>   sure that all the properties in the
>   storage model have the same type.

Other than changing the field's data type on the database side... Is there are workaround to this?

Comment: The question is a little old, but I'm having exactly the same issue. How did you get around?

Answer (score -1):

Just change the type. I would also change the name to either dept or dept_code for all tables so that it is consistent.

Comment: Asking to change a data type (not to mention the name of field) in our accounting system so I could provide a proof of concept isn't feasible at this point.  So, going on this - would your answer be that this is not doable in EF?

Comment: Most database backends will throw a fit if the data types are not the same. You can usually get around it by using CAST() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx). However, I am not sure whether ET or any other ORM will allow you to do that. Another option is to load the list of departments first and do the joining in your application code.